# Java Scheduler which starts at 9.30 am, runs every 15 minutes and ends at 8pm

Tags: java, cron, scheduler

I need *Java* @Scheduled ***annotation*** to run a scheduler which should **starts at 9.30am** and **runs every 15minutes** (ie. 9.30am, 9.45am, 10.00am, 10.15am, ... etc to 8.30pm) and **ends at 8.30pm**.

I have tried this one which starts at 9am.

> @Scheduled(cron = "0 0/15 9-20 * * *")

Can anyone help me achieve this condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track! Just minor adjustment:

```
@Scheduled(cron = "0 30/15 9-20 * * ?")
```